# Make changes to code to download attachments

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

In Excel I use the following coding to download attachments from a sub folder in my inbox, it works fine but is it possible to ONLY download attachemnts from emails that are unread?

I would appreciate any advise or help that you can give me.

I think it might be If objItem.unread Then... but i'm not entirely sure how to implement it in my coding?

```
' public objects moved from Userform code module
Public OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
Public oNameSpace    As Namespace
Public oFldrList     As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Public objItem       As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Public oSubFldrList  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Public oSubFldritem  As Outlook.MAPIFolder


Sub GetAttachments(Name As String)
       On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err
       Dim MyMail As MailItem
       Dim ns As Namespace
       Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
       Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
       Dim Item As Object
       Dim Atmt As Attachment
       Dim FileName As String
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim olItem As MailItem
       Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment

    i = 0
        If oFldrList.Folders.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox oFldrList.Name & " has no sub folders"
            MsgBox "There are " & oFldrList.Items.Count & " items in folder"
        Else
            Set SubFolder = oFldrList.Folders(Name)
           ' MsgBox SubFolder.Name & " has " & SubFolder.Items.Count & "  items folders"
        End If

        For Each olItem In SubFolder.Items
           ' MsgBox olItem.Subject & vbLf & "has " & olItem.Attachments.Count & " attachements"
            For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments
Select Case Right(olAtt.FileName, 4)
Case ".xls"
    FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case ".csv"
    FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case ".txt"
    FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case ".mp3"
       FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case ".jpg"
       FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case Else
    Select Case Right(olAtt.FileName, 5)
    Case ".xlsx"
        FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
Case ".alnk"
        FileName = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.FileName
      olAtt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
    End Select
End Select
            Next
        Next

    If i > 0 Then
          MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
             & vbCrLf & "I have saved them on the" & frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & " Path." _
             & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " ", vbInformation, "Download Finished!"
            Unload Me
       Else
          MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, _
          "Finished!"
      End If
GetAttachments_exit:
         Set Atmt = Nothing
         Set Item = Nothing
         Set ns = Nothing
         Exit Sub
GetAttachments_err:
         MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
            & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
            & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
            & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
            & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
            , vbCritical, "Error!"
         Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, though I'm not sure if `Unread` is a property only of `MailItem`s, so you may also need to check what type of object it is before trying to read the `Unread` value

```
Dim fn

For Each olItem In SubFolder.Items
   ' MsgBox olItem.Subject & vbLf & "has " & olItem.Attachments.Count & " attachements"
    If olItem.Unread Then
        For Each olAtt In olItem.Attachments

            fn = olAtt.Filename

            If fn Like "*.xls" Or fn Like "*.csv" Or fn Like "*.txt" Or _
               fn Like "*.mp3" Or fn Like "*.jpg" Or fn Like "*.xlsx" Or _
               fn Like "*.alnk" Then

                    Filename = frmdownloadattchmts.TextBox1.Value & olAtt.Filename
                    olAtt.SaveAsFile Filename
                    i = i + 1

            End If

        Next 'attachment
    End If 'unread
Next
```